# In Google App maker, How are Query Script parameters added?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to figure how to use a **DateBox** widget to filter the datasource using a **query-script**. But I don't know how to add parameter variables to the script.

When using **query-builder**, there is a special button to add query parameters. However, there is no mention in the docs on **where** to add **query parameters** when writing a **query-script**.

docs -> https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like since you asked the question docs were updated. Here is the latest code snippet from the docs:

```javascript
// Modify passed query to additionally filter by minimum age
// if client asks us to do so.
if (query.parameters.RestrictAge) {
  query.filters.Age._greaterThan = 20;
}

var employees = query.run();
```